# Use method repaint() with JLayeredPane?

Tags: java, swing, repaint, jlayeredpane

I write  simple application and I have problem with repaint().I have one JLayeredPane where I putted components. 
I want to make button reset,and when he is clicked to set JLayeredPane to default look.

```
layeredPane.removeAll();
ayeredPane.revalidate();
layeredPane.repaint();
```

But when button is clicked the JLayeredPane didn't reset to default.`

Can somebody help me how I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html). Download the demo code. It will show you how to properly structure a program.

Make the following change to the code:

```
if (ON_TOP_COMMAND.equals(cmd)) {
    layeredPane.removeAll();
    layeredPane.repaint();
```

1. Run the program to prove it displays the layered panes.
2. Click on the "Top Position in Layer" checkbox and the layers will disappear.

So you have proven the code should work. If it doesn't work for you then maybe you don't have a valid reference to the layered pane.

If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem because we can't help based on the code provided since it should work, to the problem is somewhere else in your program.